# TypeScript app: Imports via require() failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following imports in one of my viewmodels (Durandal + TypeScript):

```cs
import ko                  = require("knockout"); // Works
import http                = require("../../services/http"); // Works
import serialNumberHandler = require("services/serialNumberHandler"); // Fails
```

My Durandal app is in an ASP.NET MVC web application in a structure as follows:

```
Solution
↳ Project
 ↳ App
  ↳ services
   ↳ http.ts
   ↳ serialNumberHandler.ts
  ↳ FunctionalArea
   ↳ Feature
    ↳ viewModel.ts
 ↳ index.html
 ↳ index.ts // Contains requirejs config including paths
 ↳ tsconfig.json // Contains requirejs config including paths
```

For some reason in the import statements at the top of this post, the third one fails in Visual Studio and when running `tsc` because of the following:

[image: Visual Studio Mouseover message]

I though that putting `baseUrl: "./App" in` tsconfig.json` would fix it, but that doesn't seem to have worked.

Notice that my `index.ts` is one level above the rest of the app. Do I have a relative path issue here somewhere? This used to work (though I don't know how) before I added `tsconfig.json`, though I had other problems then (i.e. due to the lack of the `paths` section of `tsconfig.json`, none of my external modules could be found).

Comment: I see you have second import file at the same level as the third import file, but you use diferents paths... in second import your require looks like this `require("../../services/http")` and the third import looks like `require("services/serialNumberHandler")`, why the import are different if they are in the same folder/level?

Comment: One is an actual relative path (which works). The other is supposed to be relative to the `baseUrl` in either the `tsconfig.json` or `index.ts`'s `requirejs.config()` method (I'm not sure which is used), but it's not working. Like it's not picking up that `baseUrl` value somehow (or I'm putting the wrong value in it).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to correct all my `.ts` files to use `../../services/[etc]` because that'll be a pain, and `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json` is supposed to be the way to do it. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url